# How to write syscall.h for mips32 kernel?

Tags: linux-kernel, mips32

I am new to kernel stuff, I was trying to integrate LTTNG open source. This requires the dependency of the syscall.h - , unfortunately, MIPS has not written the syscall.h file for their architecture. How can I resolve this issue? Please help.